# How to set in a basic html a reference to my ticker?

Tags: html, reference, ticker

I do have following ticker:

```
<!-- 
<marquee direction="left" behavior="scroll" scrollamount="1"     scrolldelay="1" style="color:#000000;font-size:16px;font-family:Arial;" >

myreference

</marquee>
<!--
```

Now I would like to change **myreference** (which is the text in my ticker) with a (string) variable **outside** this ticker. How can I do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The HTML marquee tag may not be supported by various browsers so its not recommended to rely on this tag, instead you can use Javascript and CSS to create such effects.

I hope it help you!!!

**CSS**

```
.marquee {
    height: 25px;
    width: 420px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}

.marquee div {
    display: block;
    width: 200%;
    height: 30px;
    position: absolute;
    overflow: hidden;
    animation: marquee 5s linear infinite;
}

.marquee span {
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
}

@keyframes marquee {
    0% { left: 0; }
    100% { left: -100%; }
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="marquee">
    <div>
        <span>Your marquee here</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: and how would it looks like if using Javascript?

Comment: Hi @norick, here is an example: https://codepen.io/jamesbarnett/pen/kfmKa